# How do I implement a control system for a game in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a control system for my simple 2D game using javaFX. I did extensive research and was unable to come up with anything.

What I want to do: I want to set a series of special key events to control a ship and to bring up a pause menu. When I was trying to get a pause menu to display using something similar to this

```
gameScene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.equals(KeyCode.P) {

            }
        }
    });
```

I get a "The method setOnKeyPressed(EventHandler) in the type Scene is not applicable for the arguments (new EventHandler(){})" warning  in reference to the type argument of EventHandler. I have seen examples of this expression being used in this exact way. I want 'P' to be the key to pull up the pause menu. I am unsure why I receive this error. On a side vote I am wondering what method I should call to display a Scene or Pane?

Comment: Check your imports. Are you sure that's a `javafx.events.EventHandler` and not some unrelated `EventHandler` interface from another library?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it is having the onKeyPressed set on the Root Pane of the Scene.

So something like

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> {
    if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.P) {
        //Open Pause Menu  
    }
});
```

EDIT 1:
Don't forget to use the root to open your scene.

```
Scene gameScene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(gameScene);
stage.show();
```

Comment: Thank you Micheal for your reply! I will most definitely try your procedure. One thing I am confused by is how getCode() is not a member of the KeyEvent class.  I like your implementation better btw!

Comment: The KeyEvent has multiple functions that could be called. So I would imagine the e.equals(KeyCode.P) wpuld always return false, or throw a error, because an event isn't explicitly equal to a KeyCode. Using getCode() on the KeyEvent will return the KeyCode associated with that KeyEvent. Read the oracle docs for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html

Comment: Something for future reference Micheal; I figured out that when using setOnKeyPressed that declaring the type keyEvent is unnecessary and that just passing the argument e is adequate. I will update you on whether this is 100 percent correct or not.

Comment: If this answered your question please mark it as the answer. Also, I am eagerly awaiting an update :)